# Solve a system of non-linear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

How should I go around solving this system of non-linear equations?
$$x+\frac{1}{y} =2 \frac{1}{3}$$
$$y+\frac{1}{z}=2\frac{3}{4}$$
$$z+\frac{1}{x}=-3\frac{1}{2}$$

I managed to solve it using substitution (i.e. eliminating $x$ and $y$ in the first equation), but it seems like there might be an easier method, consider the equations appear symmetrical

Comment: does $2 \frac{1}{3}$ mean $2/3$ (as should) or $2+1/3=7/3$ as in the answer you have accepted ?

Comment: 7/3.  It's a mixed fraction.

Comment: That's absolutely a "non-standard" notation, and definitely not to appear in this site (my opinion of course), and moreover un-needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: From the first equation we get
$$y=\frac{1}{\frac{7}{3}-x}$$ and from the last one $$z=-\frac{7}{2}-\frac{1}{x}$$ so we get
$$\frac{1}{\frac{7}{3}-x}+\frac{1}{-\frac{7}{2}-\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{11}{4}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Your last equation is wrong.

Comment: And what did i wrong?

Comment: You seem to like the denominators being 3?  $y+1/z$ is 11/4 not 11/3, and $z+1/x$ is -7/2 not -7/3..

Comment: Also your second equation is wrong.

Comment: $$z=-\frac{7}{2}-\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: I think I fixed the "oopses" under discussion but is the hint still helpful after doing so?

Comment: I think better is to show me my mistake.